# pandas: filter data using column in unix timestamp

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

One column of my `dataframe` contains unix timestamp. I am looking for a way to filter records by date similar to this `SQL` statement:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE to_timestamp(log_time) < '2007-04-13';
```

to filter records in my `dataframe`. Sample record in dataframe shown below where `log_time` is between `2007-04-12` and `2007-04-13`:

```
df.head(10)
id  log_time    class
154 1176369676  A
161 1176369723  E
76  1176373591  C
97  1176381981  A
76  1176415869  C
82  1176421986  B 
154 1176421986  A
163 1176421986  B
161 1176421986  D
161 1176437973  E
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- In order to use datetime [Boolean selection](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing), the `log_time` column needs to be converted to a datetime column, or create a separate datetime column from `log_time`.
- Use [`pandas.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) and specify `unit='s'`, for this data.

```py
import pandas as pd

# setup the dataframe
data = {'id': [154, 161, 76, 97, 76, 82, 154, 163, 161, 161],
        'log_time': [1176369676, 1176369723, 1176373591, 1176381981, 1176415869, 1176421986, 1176421986, 1176421986, 1176421986, 1176437973],
        'class': ['A', 'E', 'C', 'A', 'C', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'D', 'E']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# create a datetime column from log_time
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df.log_time, unit='s')

# display(dflhead())
    id    log_time class            datetime
0  154  1176369676     A 2007-04-12 09:21:16
1  161  1176369723     E 2007-04-12 09:22:03
2   76  1176373591     C 2007-04-12 10:26:31
3   97  1176381981     A 2007-04-12 12:46:21
4   76  1176415869     C 2007-04-12 22:11:09

# select data
selected = df[df.datetime > '2007-04-13']

# display(selected)
    id    log_time class            datetime
9  161  1176437973     E 2007-04-13 04:19:33
```